# C secp256k1 : what is the purpose of secp256k1_context_randomize?

Tags: secp256k1, random

In the course of studying the secp256k1 library API, I came across`secp256k1_context_randomize` which seems similar to providing a seed to a pseudo-random generator. At the same time, the file `secp256k1.h` seemingly does not offer any functionality for generating random private keys, and the function `secp256k1_ecdsa_sign` relies on a deterministic secret (rfc 6979) rather than anything randomly generated. Now I can see the API being extended in file `secp256k1_ecdh.h` with the function `secp256k1_ecdh` which returns an EC Diffie-Hellman secret. But this doesn't seem to rely on random generation either since the scalar is provided as argument. So I am wondering, why would a user care to randomize a context, or in other words, where is randomization used with the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just merged [a PR by Rusty Russell](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/pull/441) that aims to explain its purpose. From the text that was added:

> While secp256k1 code is written to be constant-time no matter what secret values are, it's possible that a future compiler may output code which isn't, and also that the CPU may not emit the same radio frequencies or draw the same amount power for all values.
>
> This function provides a seed which is combined into the blinding value: that blinding value is added before each multiplication (and removed afterwards) so that it does not affect function results, but shields against attacks which rely on any input-dependent behaviour.
>
> You should call this after secp256k1_context_create or secp256k1_context_clone, and may call this repeatedly afterwards.